# Resize content search webpart slideshow to fit across page SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin, css, content-search-web-part

I would like to use a content search webpart slideshow mode as the banner across the top of my share point page. When I add in the webpart, it is aligned to the left and only half of the size of the webpart container. I have not been able to reconfigure the size of the WebPart.
Any hints?

Comment: You can play around with the size and position of the WebPart by editing CSS

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to change the size of the slide show by following the guide in this link

http://sp2013.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/sharepoint-content-search-web-part.html#!/2013/08/sharepoint-content-search-web-part.html

This person explains how to modify the internal template (so it is not done using CSS on top of the page).

Further documentation (but not on the slideshow)

https://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/customising-content-search-web-part.html

Comment: Is there any other ways if I do not have edit permissions to display template ? I already tried some css commands but doesn't seem to work. thanks

Comment: to be able to modify the display template you only need to have access to Site settings - Master pages and page layouts - Display templates - content web parts (basically you need to be site owner or above. If those templates are the meat and bone of the content query web part, you need to edit those to get your result. Any other approach will mean to start from scratch and create a brand new slide show webpart, which is way more difficult than the path I suggested.